# How to vertically align content without nesting additional containers?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've been having a lot of trouble with vertically aligning an item in its container.

I've implemented plenty of suggestions. All of them suggest wrapping the content in another div or container.

This has caused all sorts of issues for various reasons I won't get into but I would like to choose a new requirement: *That it not be wrapped in another container.*

That lead me to this solution (styles inline for brevity):

```
<div style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle">my content</div>
```

Or this:

```
<td style="vertical-align:middle">my content</td>
```

I like the first option more than the second because with the second you sort of go, "why is there a Table Cell in the middle of this other content that is independent of a table?"

The reason I'm hesitant to use the first option is because I'm not sure it will work in all browsers. I could say the same about the second option as well.

Which option is better in terms of semantics and browser support?

Comment: What's the question being asked here? The question title has a question, "what are other ways to vertically align my content that are better than these?" is implied, you also ask about browser support, and on first glance you seem to be asking which of the two examples is better.

Comment: Did you actually try a stand-alone `<td>` element? It won't work, because HTML parsers discard `<td>` tags that are not inside a table.

Comment: I didn't try standalone TD element. From what I gathered is that it is could work as standalone element. The answer by Michael says that the display is set by the default stylesheet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To vertically center content, without nesting additional wrappers, you can simply use [**flexbox**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

**CSS**

```
div {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;       /* center content vertically, in this case */
    justify-content: center;   /* center content horizontally, in this case (optional) */
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>my content</div>
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/os125d5x/)

*Note that although the text in the div appears to not have a container, technically when the div becomes a flex container the text becomes wrapped in an [anonymous container](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items) that becomes the flex item. This is how CSS works. If you don't wrap your content in an HTML element, CSS will create [anonymous block or inline boxes](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#anonymous-block-level).*

---

*You wrote:*

> I like the first option more than the second because the second you
>   sort of go, "why is there a Table Cell in the middle of this other
>   content that is independent of a table?
>
> The reason I'm hesitant to use the first option is because I'm not
>   sure it will work in all browsers. I could say the same about the
>   second option as well.

From a functional perspective, there is no difference between:

```
<div style="display:table-cell;">my content</div>
```

and

```
<td>my content</td>
```

Both do the same thing. Here's why:

HTML elements, including `div` and `td`, have no `display` value *until the browser applies styles with the [default stylesheet](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html)*.

Hence, the only reason a `td` acts like a table cell is because the browser's default stylesheet specifies `td { display: table-cell; }`.

You're doing the same with the `div`, by overriding the browser's `display: block` with your own `display: table-cell`.

So it's really the same thing in terms of functionality and all players – `div`, `td`, `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle` are [supported by all browsers](http://caniuse.com/) going back to at least IE6.

Browser support for flexbox, however, is not yet complete. Flexbox, which is CSS3, is supported by all major browsers, [except IE 8 & 9](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Some recent browser versions, such as Safari 8 and IE10, require [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix). For a quick way to add all the prefixes you need, post your CSS here: [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/).

---

> *As an aside:*
>
> HTML elements have no inherent styling. In other words, the tag names
>   themselves don't carry styles. It isn't until they go  through the browser that `display` and other CSS properties are applied. (See an [HTML Default
>   Stylesheet](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html).)
>
> Based on this [MDN Bug
>   Report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=984869#c7), it
>   appears that the only HTML elements who's boxes are constructed based
>   on their tag name are `<button>`, `<fieldset>` and `<legend>`.

Answer (score 3):

CSS tables are supported by about 97% of browsers, and good backwards compatibility, see http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table

I would not hesitate to use CSS tables and your example is totally reasonable.